# validating if username already exists in database by using prepared statements... how to?

Tags: php, validation, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to validate username to assure that same username does not already exist in my database. I am trying to do so using prepared statements.

What I am trying to do right now is to see if post exist by checking what STMT has returned. I'm not really sure if I'm going into right direction with this.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Although I tried what someone suggested and I am still adding duplicate username into database.

```
    if (empty($username))
    {
        $usernameError = "Required!";
    }
    else if (preg_match('/^[A-Z \'.-]{2,20}$/i', $username))
    {
        if ($stmt1 = $dbc->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?"))
        {
            $stmt1->bind_param('s', $username);

            $stmt1->execute();

            if($stmt1->num_rows>0)
            {           
                $usernameError = "Username already exists!";
            }
            else
            {
                $usernameError = "";
            }

            $stmt1->close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $usernameError = "Incorrect Username!";
    }
```

Comment: Exactly the same way as selecting any other data - by running a query against a server.

Comment: @Your Common Sense, this wouldn't be so bad, but just trying to learn to use prepared statements. Without them I wouldn't have as much trouble.

Comment: learning doesn't mean writing random code and then ask why it doesn't work. Following a tutorial is a considerable better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) method works.

(posting because can't delete question with an answer)

```
if($stmt->fetch())
{           
    $usernameError = "Username already exists!";
}
else
{
    $usernameError = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `if($stmt != FALSE)` use `if($stmt->num_rows>0)`

```
 if($stmt->num_rows>0){

   $usernameError = "Username already exists!";
}else{

    $usernameError = "";
}
```

Comment: I checked that, and I'm afraid I'm still going through the registration even when the same username already exists in the database.

Comment: +1 for pointing out my error that `STMT =! FALSE` won't work in my case.